# style.width is not working for innerWidth

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert a div dynamically with it's width equal to the page width using the  window.innerWidth property.

It doesn't seem to work and the width is set to '0' automatically.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<body onload="lb()"></body>
```

JS

```
function lb()
{
var h=window.innerHeight
||document.body.clientHeight
||document.documentElement.clientHeight;

var w=window.innerWidth
||document.body.clientWidth
||document.documentElement.clientWidth;

                    alert("Width: "+w+"\n"+"Height: "+h);

        var x=document.createElement("div");
        x.id="heder";
        x.style.width=w;
        x.style.height='150px';
        x.style.backgroundColor='#000000';
        x.style.position='absolute';
        x.style.margin='0px';
        x.style.padding='0px';

              document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xyyUy/1

Comment: whats inside the body ? Also why are you not using css alone to control this ? JS seems overkill.

Comment: body is empty, actually I'm learning this concept, so everything using js.

Comment: And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xyyUy/1/

Comment: you're better off using html and css for this kind of simple issue. On saying that, you can just get the body width and apply it to the child.. or a div immediately inside the div||body Bootstrap || Foundation css framework recommended.

Comment: May be you cannot see the div which makes you complain, try removing the line `x.style.position='absolute';` and it should reappear. P.S. use CSS for these things.

Comment: @Pogrindis absolutely, it can be achieved with basic CSS

Comment: I absolutely agree with you all, but its about time.
As soon as I learn js completely, I'll be back to html and css.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fogot to add "**px**" with width value

should be

```
    x.style.width=w+"px";
```

instead of

```
    x.style.width=w;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Suman Bogati said you need to add the 'px'. Also your Fiddle was throwing an error executing the lb() function. I tweaked it in this fiddle to work. I just did a simple call to

```
lb();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyyUy/2/